# WPF C# Two-Way Data Bind Not Working

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I recognize that this question is similar to others, but the others have not worked in my situation.  I am trying to Two-Way Bind a textbox in my WPF to an XML file.

The data comes in perfectly into the textbox, but when I edit the textbox, the XML file is never changed.  Based on what I have found online, my code seems like it should work.  Here it is:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Learning_0._002.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main Window" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
  Height="400" Width="950">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="BusinessInfo" Source="BusinessData.xml" XPath="/Businesses/Business"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="BusinessInfo" DataContext="{StaticResource BusinessInfo}">

        <TextBox Name="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="106,93,717,250"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

BusinessData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Businesses>
  <Business Name="Sample Company" Address="1234 East Road St. City, California 90068" Phone="555-555-5555" Fax="555-555-5556" Email="myemail@example.net" Website="www.example.com"/>
</Businesses>
```

I am new to this, and cannot find my error.  Any corrections are appreciated!

Comment: I don't think two-way binding works against XML data sources, and even if it did, it wouldn't flush the changes out to disk.

Comment: Will it help you? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26875/WPF-XmlDataProvider-Two-Way-Data-Binding

Comment: And as mentioned in the above link `the XmlDataProvider does not natively support two-way binding.`.

Comment: `the XML file is never changed` - that's not how DataBinding works. Sounds like your XML file is part of the project? I meean do you see it in the Solution Explorer? If so, it's never going to be changed at runtime, you need to copy it to output directory and save it like the above link shows.

Comment: @HighCore-- Yes, the XML file is part of the project.  In case it matters, I am using Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: @dizel3d--  Well, I tried that, but it keeps throwing all kinds of errors when I try to test the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a question that is very similar to yours - 
[WPF two-way binding XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294255/wpf-two-way-binding-xml)

It looks like what you need to do is instead of using a Grid.Resources you need use a datacontext instead. If you're going to be doing more advanced work I would recommend you use a class that contains all the data behind your UI elements. View this MSDN for more information - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

`<Grid.DataContext>
    <XmlDataProvider  x:Name="XMLData" Source="BusinessData.xml" XPath="/Businesses/Business"/>
</Grid.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="BusinessInfo"  Margin="98,49,118,144">
    <TextBox Name="Name"  Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="Name_TextChanged" />
</Grid>`

And then in C# you will save it whenever they enter text into the textbox

`private void Name_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    XMLData.Document.Save("XMLFile1.xml");
}`

You should know that when you save the file it will save to the same directory as where you run your executable. You can of course change where you save it to be the actual source of the XML.

Comment: That is not working.  There are no errors thrown, but the file does not get edited.

Comment: Did you check your output directory to make sure `XMLFile1.xml` is actually created and saving? I did not name it the same as `BusinessData.xml` and it probably is not the same path as where you have it referenced.

Comment: I changed your code to be BusinessData.xml.   Will I see the changes in Visual Studio, though?

Comment: Only if you have the correct file open. If you will want to modify the location of where you save. If you have the XML file in the root of your solution you can simply change the line that saves to this: `XMLData.Document.Save("../../BusinessData.xml");`

Comment: Alright so when you call the line `XMLData.Document.Save("XMLFile1.xml");` that saves the file in wherever you are running the file. For example let's say your application was called `app.exe` and it was located in `C:\Test\app.exe` then the XML that would be saved would be located in `C:\Test\XMLFile.xml`. What I am trying to say is that when you call `XMLData.Document.Save("BusinessData.xml");` You will need to make sure that the you're saving the XML file to same place where the XAML file is referencing it from. Try looking at your project in the file explorer to see any duplicate XML files

Comment: Okay, almost there.  I used that article you referenced, and that works okay-- Visual Studio says "a file was updated, do you want to refresh?".  However, when I click on "Yes" to refresh it, the file isn't actually changed.  Why is that?